# Move html block without before pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

Let's look at this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f3uxbo2o/5/)**. Here is a calendar, that I can move from left to right. This calendar is moving with `::before` triangle. It's not good behaviour and I want to move it without triangle. Is it possible to do it? Preferably without js.

```js
$('[type="range"]').on('input change', () => {
  $('.calendar').css('left', $('[type="range"]').val() + 'px');
})
```

```css
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.calendar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ccc transparent;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="day">1</div>
  <div class="day">2</div>
  <div class="day">3</div>
  <div class="day">4</div>
  <div class="day">5</div>
  <div class="day">6</div>
  <div class="day">7</div>
  <div class="day">8</div>
  <div class="day">9</div>
  <div class="day">10</div>
</div>

<input type="range", min="50", max="200", value="70">
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the triangle, or move the calender while the triangle stays at it's location?

Comment: @RicoBrassers yes. move the calender while the triangle stays at it's location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes in your code and it seems to work :).

CSS:

```
.ct {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 200px;
}
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.ct:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ccc transparent;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <body>
  <div class="ct">
    <div class="calendar">
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">2</div>
      <div class="day">3</div>
      <div class="day">4</div>
      <div class="day">5</div>
      <div class="day">6</div>
      <div class="day">7</div>
      <div class="day">8</div>
      <div class="day">9</div>
      <div class="day">10</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="range", min="50", max="200", value="70">
</body>
```

Basicly, i've added parent container which have pseudo-selector (arrow) and this one is not moving. Moving part is .calendar only.

Answer (score 0):

**Update css**

```
 .calendar:before {
      display:none;
    }
```

Add this the arrow will hide.
Or remove that .calendar:before class.